# if statement in r?

Tags: r, eigenvalue

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
ee <- eigen(crossprod(X))$values
for(i in 1:length(ee)){
if(ee[i]==0:1e^-9) stop("singular Matrix")}
```

Using the eigen value approach, I am trying to determine if the matrix is singular or not. I am attempting to find out if one of the eigen values of the matrix is between 0 and 10^-9. How can I use the if statement (as above) correctly to achieve my goal?  Is there any other way to approach this?

what if I want to concatenate the zero eigen value in vector

```
zer <-NULL
ee <- eigen(crossprod(X))$values 
for(i in 1:length(ee)){ 
if(abs(ee[i])<=1e-9)zer <- c(zer,ee[i])}
```

Can I do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to convey in the condition of your if statement?

Comment: You've already asked a few questions, yet you have not voted a single answer up, nor accepted one. Please consider doing so (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @flodel I am new to the site and still getting the hang of things. thank you for the advice

Comment: There is no need for the for loop for either part, see my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AriBFriedman is quite correct. I can, however see a couple of other issues

- `1e^-9` should be `1e-9`.
- `0:1e-9` returns `0`, (`:` creates a sequence by one between 0 and 1e-9, therefore returns just `0`. See `` ?`:` `` for more details
- Using `==` with decimals  will cause problems due to  floating point arithmetic

In the form written, your code checks (individually) whether the elements `ee[i] == 0`, which is not what you want (nor does it make sense in terms floating point arithmetic)

You are looking for cases where the eigen value is less than this small number, so use less than (`<`).

What you are looking for is something like

```
if(any(abs(ee) < 1e-9))  stop('singular matrix')
```

If you want to get the `0` (or small) eigen vectors, then use `which`

```
# this will give the indexs (which elements are small)
small_values <- which(abs(ee) < 1e-9))
# and those small values
ee[small_values]
```

There is no need for the `for` loop as everything being done is vectorized.

Comment: you are right 0:1e-9 will return zero and I was awware of 1e^-9 I just wrote like this to identify that this is a small number.

Comment: If you post code that does not work and ask to fix it, there is no point in putting in *known* syntax errors!

Answer (score 2):

`if` takes a single argument *of length 1*.

Try either `ifelse` or using `any()` or `all()` to turn your vector of logicals into a logical vector of length 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example reproducing your data:

```
X <- matrix(1:10,1:10)
ee <- eigen(crossprod(X))$values
```

This will test `if` `any` of the values of `ee` are `> 0` AND`< 1e-9`

```
if (any((ee > 0) & (ee < 1e-9))) {stop("singular matrix")}
```